# SignalR Persistent connection android

Tags: android, signalr

My server using signalr persistent connection and I want to connect my android device to it, but no luck. Can someone explain me how can i do this (any links or examples), or i must use hubs. Thanks

Comment: What are your current approaches and what do you meant by no luck ?